# How to break up columns into invervals of size 0.02 of a histogram on the x-axis?

Tags: r, statistics, histogram

How can I breakup the columns into intervals of size 0.02 on the x-axis of a histogram in R-Studio?

```
eye = LEFTEYE$X__1
breaks = seq(0.04, 1.08, by=0.02)
eye.cut = cut(eye, breaks, right=FALSE)

eye.freq = table(eye.cut)
cbind(eye.freq)

hist(eye.freq, xlab="Cylindrical Power Measurements for the Left Eye")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the breaks argument in hist(). Breaks takes the upper and lower bounds of the x-axis and then the bin width with the argument by.

For example, this code uses the iris data set and sets the lower bound of the x-axis to 4, the upper bound to 8 and sets the bin width to 0.02.

`hist(iris$Sepal.Length, breaks=seq(4,8,by=0.02))`

[image: Example histogram]

Comment: Thanks! That code helped me with the x-axis but now the y-axis (frequency) cuts off at 4 even if I change ylim = c(0,10). There are frequencies that are higher than for so this is a problem.

Comment: @Boognish `hist(iris$Sepal.Length, breaks=seq(0,10,by=0.02))` should work, the xlim is set in the breaks argument